# Zero gravity spacewalk above low Earth orbit?

Tags: eva

There have been a lot of spacewalks in LEO and there have been moonwalks too. Voskhod, Gemini, Soyuz, Apollo, Skylab, Mir, Space Shuttle and ISS.

But what about EVAs above LEO and below the orbit of the Moon? What was the biggest distance to Earth when performing a zero gravity EVA?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There have been four non-LEO EVAs performed by the Apollo astronauts.  Wikipedia has a [nice list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_spacewalks_and_moonwalks_1965%E2%80%931999).

- Apollo 15 - one in lunar orbit (visual identification of landing
  sites), one on the return flight (collect film from exterior of
  spacecraft).
- Apollo 16 - on the return flight to collect film and
  experiments from exterior of spacecraft
- Apollo 17 - on the return
  flight to collect film and experiments from exterior of spacecraft

Comment: For [Apollo 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_16#Return_to_Earth), a distance for the EVA is given: 310,000 km. But no information about Apollo 15 and 16.

Comment: The first Apollo 15 EVA was in lunar orbit.  I'd have to research the trans-lunar ones.